# How to delete detail item using Entity Framework Code First

Tags: ef-code-first

Let's say my model looks like this (stripped down for simplicity):

```
public class Deal
    {
        [Key]
        public int DealId { get; set; }

        //one Deal may have many pictures
        public virtual List<Picture> Pictures { get; set; } 

        public Deal()
        {
            Pictures = new List<Picture>();
        }       
    }
```

Whenever i want to remove a specific Picture from the Pictures list i do the following:

```
Deal deal = dealRepository.GetAll().Where(d => d.DealId == id).FirstOrDefault();
deal.Pictures.RemoveAll(p => p.Criterion.Equals(SomeCriterion));
unitOfWork.Commit();
```

It looks that everything works fine but having a look at the dbms, i see that the record supposed to be deleted, still exists, **but** with it's foreign key set to null.

Is there a way to actually delete the record?

Comment: You probably should be removing the Pictures of your DbContext... your code now it is just removing the pictures from the Deal. So you need to have something like myDbContext.Pictures.Remove(picture) to actually delete it

Comment: @Leo I 'm using a generic repository pattern. This means that i would have to use the according pictureRepository and then delete it from there. I will give this a try!

Answer (score 2):

You need to do the following to delete the records:

```
foreach (var picture in deal.Pictures.Where(theCondition).ToList())
    dbContext.Set<Picture>().Remove(picture);
```

You could use `dbContext.Pictures` instead of `.Set<Picture>()` if you have such a property

Of course, since you've built an extra abstraction on top of DbContext (the repository), you'll need to expose that call somewhere.